# How to handle ACK frame on server side using Spring websocket STOMP?

Tags: spring-websocket

Background:
I'm trying to tunnel internal HTTP server to public via a proxy server for my clients.

[internal http server] N <=(websocket)=> 1 [public proxy server] 1 <=(http)=> N [clients]

(The 'internal http server' and client app pairs are owned by clients, the proxy server is providing a service to allow user tunnel their own internal http server, this is like ngrok.)

A typical process:

1. client send HTTP "GET /portfolio" to the proxy server
2. proxy server send STOMP **MESSAGE** to internal http server
3. The internal http server responses with **ACK** (I want the body contains the actual portfolio)
4. The proxy server then reply the 'GET /portfolio' request to client.

But I didn't find a easy way to receive **ACK frame** by using **spring websocket STOMP**.

SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend doesn't return a value.

Any ideas or suggestions?

**---Update---**

Got exception: 'ACK shouldn't have a payload.'

I may need to use 'SEND' instead.

Comment: Or should I abandon the whole spring STOMP, and use lower level websocket API?

Comment: Or should I use 'SEND' frame instead?

Comment: Have you tried `StompClient` on the matter: docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-client ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I need to handle ACK on server side, not client side. On client side, it is a C++ application using cpprestsdk.

Comment: ??? 
> proxy server send STOMP
> The internal http server responses with ACK.      

That really means that your  proxy server is a WebSocket *client* to the  internal http server. What am I missing?

Comment: @ArtemBilan from business POV, the 'internal http server' should be the server, but because it is 'internal', it can not be connected outside (including the proxy server), thus from 'STOMP' POV, it is client who initiates the 'CONNECT' to the proxy server.